# image rotation with mouse

Tags: mouse, raphael, rotation

I try to rotate an image in Raphael. It should work like Free Form in Photoshop

here is my attempt:
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/96mAv/2/)

to rotate the pic go to its upper right corner. (cursor should change)

Answer (score 5):

You can use this plugin: http://alias.io/raphael/free_transform/